# Go to specifc row in wx.grid

Tags: python, wxpython, wxgrid

I have wx.grid filled with data and I have search option so when user enters some text, I find it and select that row. The problem is that row only gets selected but doesnt become visible. It doesnt scroll down or up to that row. How can I manually scroll to that row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MakeCellVisible( int row, int col )` — forces the particular cell to be visible, effectively works to scroll the grid to be given cell.

Comment: No problem - had the same issue myself a little while back.